# DEBUG log not written with different levels associated to different output

Tags: python, logging

I use `logging` to manage the logs of my Python's code. I will configure two different outputs (stream and file) with specific level of logs for each output. The trouble is that the DEBUG level is not written in my file while I declare to use the right level...

**MWE**:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
f = logging.FileHandler('log.log')
f.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger().addHandler(f)
logging.info('test')
logging.debug('test debug')
```

`print(logging.getLogger().handlers)` returns `[<StreamHandler <stderr> (NOTSET)>, <FileHandler zz/xxx/log.log (DEBUG)>]`

Comment: Notice that I can't start by instanciating the filehandler.

Comment: Refet to the diagram here: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-flow - the level must be set in the logger and also in the handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used `basicConfig` to set the level of the root logger to `INFO`. This means only logs with level of `INFO` and above will be accepted.

Your handler has level of `DEBUG` and is attached to the root logger with level`INFO`. So only the logs with level of `INFO` and above will be processed.

Don’t use basicConfig! You should explicitly config your logger with level of `DEBUG` and add 2 handlers, one to stdout with level `INFO` and one to file with level `DEBUG`